# Implementing an efficient queue in Python

Tags: python, queue

I have been trying to implement a queue in Python, and I've been running into a problem.

I am attempting to use lists to implement the queue data structure. However I can't quite figure out how to make `enqueue` and `dequeue` O(1) operations.

Every example I have seen online, seems to just append the `enqueue` operation and remove the first element from the list for the `dequeue` operation. But this would make the `dequeue` operation O(n) (where n is the size of the list) correct?

Is there something basic I have missed? Or do you have to use LinkedLists to implement a Queue efficiently?

```
import unittest

class Queue:
    def __init__(self):
        self._queue = []
        self.size = 0
        self.maxSize = 10

    def enqueue(self, item):
        if self.size < self.maxSize:
            self._queue.append(item)

    def dequeue(self):
        '''
        Removes an item from the front of the list. Remove first element of
        the array
        '''
        first = self._queue[0]
        del self._queue[0]
        return first
```

Comment: Why not use `collections.deque` ?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

As [Uri Goren](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1097347/uri-goren) astutely [noted above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45688871/implementing-an-efficient-queue-in-python#comment78335497_45688871), the Python stdlib already implemented an efficient queue on your fortunate behalf: [`collections.deque`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#deque-objects).

### What Not to Do

Avoid reinventing the wheel by hand-rolling your own:

- [Linked list implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48459059/2809027). While doing so reduces the worst-case time complexity of your `dequeue()` and `enqueue()` methods to O(1), the `collections.deque` type already does so. It's also thread-safe and presumably more space and time efficient, given its C-based heritage.
- [Python list implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48577248/2809027). As I [note below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45688871/implementing-an-efficient-queue-in-python#comment85545411_48577248), implementing the `enqueue()` methods in terms of a Python list increases its worst-case time complexity to **O(n).** Since removing the last item from a C-based array and hence Python list is a constant-time operation, implementing the `dequeue()` method in terms of a Python list retains the same worst-case time complexity of O(1). But who cares? `enqueue()` remains pitifully slow.

To quote the [official `deque` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#deque-objects):

> Though `list` objects support similar operations, they are optimized for fast fixed-length operations and incur O(n) memory movement costs for `pop(0)` and `insert(0, v)` operations which change both the size and position of the underlying data representation.

More critically, `deque` *also* provides out-of-the-box support for a maximum length via the `maxlen` parameter passed at initialization time, obviating the need for manual attempts to limit the queue size (which inevitably breaks thread safety due to race conditions implicit in if conditionals).

### What to Do

Instead, implement your `Queue` class in terms of the standard `collections.deque` type as follows:

```
from collections import deque

class Queue:
    '''
    Thread-safe, memory-efficient, maximally-sized queue supporting queueing and
    dequeueing in worst-case O(1) time.
    '''


    def __init__(self, max_size = 10):
        '''
        Initialize this queue to the empty queue.

        Parameters
        ----------
        max_size : int
            Maximum number of items contained in this queue. Defaults to 10.
        '''

        self._queue = deque(maxlen=max_size)


    def enqueue(self, item):
        '''
        Queues the passed item (i.e., pushes this item onto the tail of this
        queue).

        If this queue is already full, the item at the head of this queue
        is silently removed from this queue *before* the passed item is
        queued.
        '''

        self._queue.append(item)


    def dequeue(self):
        '''
        Dequeues (i.e., removes) the item at the head of this queue *and*
        returns this item.

        Raises
        ----------
        IndexError
            If this queue is empty.
        '''

        return self._queue.pop()
```

The proof is in the hellish pudding:

```
>>> queue = Queue()
>>> queue.enqueue('Maiden in Black')
>>> queue.enqueue('Maneater')
>>> queue.enqueue('Maiden Astraea')
>>> queue.enqueue('Flamelurker')
>>> print(queue.dequeue())
Flamelurker
>>> print(queue.dequeue())
Maiden Astraea
>>> print(queue.dequeue())
Maneater
>>> print(queue.dequeue())
Maiden in Black
```

### It Is Dangerous to Go Alone

Actually, **don't do that either.**

You're better off just using a raw `deque` object rather than attempting to manually encapsulate that object in a `Queue` wrapper. The `Queue` class defined above is given *only* as a trivial demonstration of the general-purpose utility of the `deque` API.

The `deque` class provides [significantly more features](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#deque-objects), including:

> ...iteration, pickling, `len(d)`, `reversed(d)`, `copy.copy(d)`, `copy.deepcopy(d)`, membership testing with the in operator, and subscript references such as `d[-1]`.

Just use `deque` anywhere a single- or double-ended queue is required. That is all.

Comment: In your example, shouldn't `Maiden in Black` be the first thing off the queue?  I would think your `dequeue` method would use `self._queue.popleft()` (`popleft` instead of `pop`).  Then again, this just goes to show another problem with rolling one's own. :)

Comment: Related to what @lindes wrote, what's implemented in this answer is sometimes referred to as a last in first out (LIFO) queue, but its more commonly called a stack. The word 'queue' by itself is widely used to refer to a first in first out (FIFO) queue, hence the confusion.

Comment: Your code comment says collections.dequeue is "memory efficient", yet each node contains twice as many pointers as  needed here (since all that is needed is a singly linked list, you don't need the back-links).  This is just like recommending using a binary tree data structure in order to implement a singly linked list (by using only the left child pointer and ignoring the right one), isn't it?

Comment: Reinventing the wheel should not be included in "What not to do". It is instructive to try to implement basic data structures. Of course dequeue will be much faster, but this is not the answer to the OP's question. I have implemented a queue and compared it with linkedlist approach and using deque. The difference in performance is not horribly bad (x8 slower) and they are usable in non-performance critical parts of the code. For details see my answer below.

Answer (score 8):

You can keep head and tail node instead of a queue list in `queue class`

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, item = None):
        self.item = item
        self.next = None
        self.previous = None


class Queue:
    def __init__(self):
        self.length = 0
        self.head = None
        self.tail = None

    def enqueue(self, value):
        newNode = Node(value)
        if self.head is None:
            self.head = self.tail = newNode
        else:
            self.tail.next = newNode
            newNode.previous = self.tail
            self.tail = newNode
        self.length += 1

    def dequeue(self):
        item = self.head.item
        self.head = self.head.next 
        self.length -= 1
        if self.length == 0:
            self.tail = None
        return item
```

Answer (score 1):

Queue implementation using list in Python, handling enqueue and dqueue as per inbuild queue data structure:

```
class queue:

    def __init__(self, max_size, size=0, front=0, rear=0):
        self.queue = [[] for i in range(5)] #creates a list [0,0,0,0,0]
        self.max_size = max_size
        self.size = size
        self.front = front
        self.rear = rear
    

    def enqueue(self, data):
        if not self.isFull():
            self.queue[self.rear] = data
            self.rear = int((self.rear + 1) % self.max_size)
            self.size += 1
        else:
            print('Queue is full')

    def dequeue(self):
        if not self.isEmpty():
            print(self.queue[self.front], 'is removed')
            self.front = int((self.front + 1) % self.max_size)
            self.size -= 1
        else:
            print('Queue is empty')

    def isEmpty(self):
        return self.size == 0

    def isFull(self):
        return self.size == self.max_size

    def show(self):
        print ('Queue contents are:')
        for i in range(self.size):
            print (self.queue[int((i+self.front)% self.max_size)])

        # driver program
        q = queue(5)
        q.enqueue(1)
        q.enqueue(2)
        q.enqueue(3)
        q.enqueue(4)
        q.enqueue(5)
        q.dequeue()
        q.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

Python's own queue implementation deque is implemented directly as [C code in CPython](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.8.1/Modules/_collectionsmodule.c). So it is very hard to match its performance with pure Python code. But this should not deter you from trying (unlike [what @Cecil Curry said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49271775/6087087)), because it makes you learn better.

Shaon shaonty implemented it as a linked list. I have implemented it using dictionaries as follows:

```
class Queue:
    slots = ['_dict','_max_item','_min_item','_min_reshape_countdown_length', '_reshape_countdown']
    
    def __init__(self):
        #-------- Imlementation Constants ---------
        self._min_reshape_countdown_length = 1000
        #-------------------------------------------
        
        self._dict = {}
        self._max_item = None
        self._min_item = None
        self._reshape_countdown = self._min_reshape_countdown_length
    
    def appendleft(self, item): #queue method, named to be consistent with deque
        if not self._dict: #If the queue is empty
            self._dict = {0:item}
            self._max_item = self._min_item = 0
        else:
            self._dict[self._min_item - 1] = item
            self._min_item -= 1
        
        if self._reshape_countdown == 0:
            self._reshape_countdown = max(len(self._dict), self._min_reshape_countdown_length)
            self._reshape()
        else:
            self._reshape_countdown -=1
        
    def pop(self): #dequeue method, named to be consistent with deque
        if not self._dict:
            raise IndexError('Queue is empty!')
            
        item = self._dict[self._max_item]
        del self._dict[self._max_item]
        if not self._dict: #item was the last element
            self._max_item = self._min_item = None
        else:
            self._max_item -= 1
        
        if self._reshape_countdown == 0:
            self._reshape_countdown = max(len(self._dict), self._min_reshape_countdown_length)
            self._reshape()
        else:
            self._reshape_countdown -=1
        
        return item
        
    def _reshape(self):
        if not self._dict: #if empty, no reshaping is needed
            return
        
        positives = max(0, self._max_item)
        negatives = -min(0, self._min_item)
        size = len(self._dict)
        
        #If the data is evenly distributed around 0, then reshaping is not
        #necessary.
        if positives > size/3 and negatives > size/3:
            return
        
        center = (self._min_item + self._max_item)//2
        self._dict = {key-center: value for key,value in self._dict.items()}
        self._max_item = self._max_item - center
        self._min_item = self._min_item - center
```

Note that this is not a good implementation to use for large queues, since creating large integers would be a problem. One can solve that problem by dividing the queue into blocks each having a dictionary of some fixed size.

I have compared [the linked list implementation of Shaon shaonty](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48459059/6087087), my implementation with dicts, and collections.deque with the following code:

```
import random

operations = []

queue_commands = 0
dequeue_commands = 0
for i in range(1000000):
    if queue_commands > dequeue_commands:
        operations.append(('q',random.random()) if random.random() < 1/2 else ('d',None))
    else:
        operations.append(('q',random.random()))
    
    if operations[-1][0] == 'q':
        queue_commands += 1
    else:
        dequeue_commands += 1

def test_case(queue):
    for command, element in operations:
        if command == 'q':
            queue.appendleft(element)
        else:
            queue.pop()
```

the results are

```
%timeit test_case(Linked_Queue())
796 ms ± 2.13 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit test_case(Queue())
838 ms ± 1.5 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit test_case(deque())
120 ms ± 566 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

As I said, it is not easy to beat deque with raw Python code:

```
class Dummy:

    def appendleft(self,item):
        pass

    def pop(self):
        pass

%timeit test_case(Dummy())
176 ms ± 327 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my implementation of Queue using array, `enqueue` and `dequeue` are both O(1) operations. The implementation is based on CLRS.

```py
class Queue:
    def __init__(self, length):
        """a queue of at most n elements using an array of n+1 element size"""
        self.length = length
        self.queue = [None]*(length+1)
        self.head = 0
        self.tail = 0

    def enqueue(self, x):
        if self.is_full():
            return 'Overflow'
        self.queue[self.tail] = x
        if self.tail == self.length:
            self.tail = 0
        else:
            self.tail = self.tail + 1

    def dequeue(self):
        if self.is_empty():
            return 'Underflow'
        x = self.queue[self.head]
        if self.head == self.length:
            self.head = 0
        else:
            self.head = self.head + 1
        return x

    def is_empty(self):
        if self.head == self.tail:
            return True
        return False

    def is_full(self):
        if self.head == self.tail+1 or (self.head == 0 and self.tail == self.length):
            return True
        return False
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# Linear Queue Implementation using Array
class Queue:
    """Class with List as Array """
    def __init__(self):
        self.v_list=[]
    """Storing the in FIFO order"""
    def enqueue(self,value):
        self.v_list.append(value)
   """Removing Element from Queue in FIFO order"""
    def dequeue(self):
        if len(self.v_list)==0:
            print('Queue is Empty')
            return
        self.v_list.pop(0)

    def print_queue(self):
        print(self.v_list)

    def size_of_queue(self):
        return print(len(self.v_list))

object_queue=Queue()
object_queue.enqueue(0)
object_queue.enqueue(1)
object_queue.enqueue(2)
object_queue.enqueue(3)
object_queue.enqueue(4)
object_queue.enqueue(5)
object_queue.print_queue()
object_queue.dequeue()
object_queue.print_queue()
object_queue.dequeue()
object_queue.print_queue()
object_queue.size_of_queue()

#Circular Queue Implementation using Array
class CircularQueue():
    def __init__(self):
        """Class to hold the Postions for insert and delete"""
        self.start_pointer=0
        self.end_pointer=-1
        self.queue_list=[]
    """Storing the element in Circular order, with circular we can remove empty Block"""
    def enqueue(self,value):
        if len(self.queue_list)>10:
            print("Circular Queue is Full")
            return
        """Checking for Empty Block in Array and storing data and reseting the stat end point to process the element"""
        if 'None' in self.queue_list:
            self.queue_list[self.end_pointer]=value
            self.end_pointer+=1
        else:
            self.queue_list.append(value)
            self.end_pointer+=1
    """Removing element In FIFO order and reseting start ending point"""
    def dequeue(self):
        #self.queue_list.replace(self.queue_list[self.start_pointer],None)
        self.queue_list = [str(sub).replace(str(self.queue_list[self.start_pointer]),'None') for sub in self.queue_list] 
        self.start_pointer+=1
        for i ,j in enumerate(self.queue_list):
            if j=='None':
                self.end_pointer=i
                break
    """For Printing Queue"""            
    def print_cq(self):
        if len(self.queue_list)>10:
            print("Circular Queue is Full")
            return
        print(self.queue_list,self.start_pointer,self.end_pointer)


cir_object=CircularQueue()
cir_object.enqueue(0)
cir_object.enqueue(1)
cir_object.enqueue(2)
cir_object.enqueue(3)
cir_object.enqueue(4)
cir_object.enqueue(5)
cir_object.enqueue(6)
cir_object.enqueue(7)
cir_object.enqueue(8)
cir_object.enqueue(9)
#cir_object.print_cq()
cir_object.dequeue()
cir_object.dequeue()
cir_object.print_cq()
cir_object.enqueue(15)
cir_object.enqueue(20)
cir_object.print_cq()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Queue:
    def __init__(self,no):
        self.no = no 
        self.SQueue = []
        self.front = -1
        self.rear = -1
    def insert(self):
        if self.rear == self.no -1:
            print("Queue is Full.....")
        else:           
            if self.front == -1:
                self.front = 0
                self.rear = 0
            else :
                self.rear += 1
            n = int(input("enter an element :: "))
            self.SQueue.insert(self.rear, n)

    def delete(self):
        if self.front == -1 and self.front == no - 1:
            print("Queue is Empty.....")
        else:
            self.SQueue.pop(self.front)
            self.front +=1
    def disp(self):
        if self.front == -1 and self.front == no - 1:
            print("Queue is Empty.....")
        else:
            print("REAR \tELEMENT")
            for i in range(len(self.SQueue)):
                print(i," \t",self.SQueue[i])

no = int(input("ENTER  Size :: "))
q = Queue(no)
while(True):
    print(" 1: INSERT ")
    print(" 2: DELETE ")
    print(" 3: PRINT ")
    print(" 4: EXIT ")
    option = int(input("enter your choice :: "))

    if option == 1:
        q.insert()
 
    elif option == 2:
        q.delete()

    elif option == 3:
        q.disp()

    elif option == 4:
        print("you are exit!!!!!")
        break
    else:
        print("Incorrect option")
```

Answer (score -2):

In dequeue method there is no any loop. You only have to do list operations. Therefore the time complexity for dequeue is also O(n)(linear).

```
class Queue:
    def __init__(self):
       self.items=[]
    def enqueue(self,item):
       self.items.append(item)
    def dequeue(self):
       return self.items.pop(0)
    def isEmpty(self):
       return self.items==[]
    def __len__(self):
       return len(self.items)
```

Comment: **No.** Python lists are internally implemented as [C arrays](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) rather than linked lists. While the average and amortized worst-case times for appending to Python lists *is* O(1), the non-amortized worst-case time for the above `self.items.append(item)` call is **O(n)** (i.e., linear rather than constant). Ergo, your `enqueue` implementation *does* effectively contain an implicit loop. While that loop is presumably implemented via an efficient assembly-based contiguous memory copy, efficient alternatives requiring *no* such copy are well-known.